# What's an uncumbersome way to translate "[he was not] that much of a cartoon supervillain" into Spanish?

Tags: traducción, gramática

I drafted a little 4-minute speech in English which I translated into Spanish and have so far presented once online to a Spanish tutor of mine.

Near the beginning of the speech I have somewhat of a throw-away line in which I say something silly about Alexander the Great, followed by:

> ... and Alexander the Great probably wasn't that much of a
> Saturday-morning cartoon supervillain.

The translation I attempted at first went like so:

> ... y Alejandro Magno probablemente no era tan mucho un supervillano
> de dibujos animados de sábado por la mañana.

That adjective-cluster at the end, describing "supervillano", is so clunky that I had to simply cut out the "Saturday-morning" part of the clause. (As far as I know there's no other way to say that apart from "[de] sábado por la mañana..." is there?)

The final presentation to my tutor was:

> ... **y Alejandro Magno probablemente no era tan mucho un supervillano
> de dibujos animados.**

Perhaps because it's still quite an inelegant phrase, my tutor thought I should've just simply said "he wasn't that much of a supervillain", which, however, does not convey the same meaning that I'm going for.

Also she seemed to have an issue with the grammar around "no era tan mucho un", which she seemed to be telling me should rather be "no era tan***to*** mucho un". Is she right about this?

(Such nuances of grammar are difficult to navigate in this case since my Spanish level is intermediate at best, while her English seems to be at the same level as my Spanish.)

Overall, is there a more concise way to say this while still conveying the same sense of meaning? As in: *Cartoons often feature over-the-top supervillain characters. And Alexander the Great was like one of them, but not to such a great extent.*

Or is my current phrasing essentially as good as it gets?

Comment: I think a better translation for cartoon would be "caricatura". "Dibujos animados" sounds as clunky or old-fashioned as saying "animated drawings/pictures" in English.

Comment: Hmmm... Okay, so in [this] context, in Spanish, would _caricaturas_ ordinarily convey the sense of _a piece of animation_ , as opposed to simply _a still image_ (like the case would be with English "caricatures" in the latter instance)?

Comment: "caricaturas" doesn't differentiate on that. We don't have two words to separate those meanings, as far as I know. [The definition](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/caricatura) includes "Dibujos animados", and I've never heard of a kid use the term "dibujos animados". They always say "caricaturas" when requesting use of the TV, in my experience.

Comment: Caricatures like those found on newspapers would also be called "caricaturas", just to make that clear. [Here's the definition in the RAE.](https://dle.rae.es/caricatura)... where I'm seeing that it's use for animated drawings is particular to my country... Now I'm curious if kids in other  countries really use "dibujos animados"...

Comment: Maybe in other countries "dibujos animados" sounds clunky, but in Spain it sounds very natural.

Comment: "Dibujos animados" is the only term I have ever used (Spain). I guess this is a regional thing.

Comment: I find such regional semantic variations so interesting, so I'm grateful that you've all chimed in! @JoL , the 3rd WordReference.com entry that you've pointed out seems to be saying that such a use of _caricaturas_ is (at least particularly) an American thing(?), if I've understood the " _amer._ " in the entry correctly. Thanks for the even more country-specific RAE references too :)

Comment: "an American thing(?)" -- Probably American in the sense of the [Americas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas) rather than just the US. [The Spanish Wikipedia article for "Dibujos Animados"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dibujo_animado) also says, "conocido como caricatura, comiquita o dibujito en zonas de Hispanoamérica o con el anglicismo cartoon". So, I guess the choices are not limited to just those 2 terms. Checking the RAE, I find [comiquita](https://dle.rae.es/comiquita?m=form) is apparently used in Venezuela for animated drawings.

Comment: Oh, "Hispanoamérica" & the Americas in general is precisely the sense in which I meant that, _rather than_ the US. (& I'm assuming WordReference means it in the same way too[?]...) That actually brings up what I think will be my next official Question: about the use of the term "America" in Spanish vs in English (though I'd be surprised if it hasn't come up on here before.) But anyway, more interesting stuff you've found! The tutor in Question here is venezolana! So maybe _comiquita_ would make sense to her in this context. Hmmm... Does _dibujito_ imply animation or "a little drawing"?

Comment: "Does dibujito imply animation or 'a little drawing'?" -- In México, it's always "little drawing", never an animation. If the Wikipedia article is to be believed, there's some place where it can mean animation. The RAE doesn't seem to say where, so "Where does dibujito mean animated drawing?" might be a good question for this site if you're interested.

Comment: Ah, okay. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first comment is that one never writes "tan mucho" (or "tanto mucho") in Spanish. Comparison of equality ("[*so/as*] + [adj./adv.] + *as*") is translated into Spanish as "*tan* + [adj./adv.] + *como*", but if one is comparing amounts of **nouns** ("*as [much/many]* + noun + *as*"), one says "[*tanto/tanta/tantos/tantas*] + noun + *como*". You can think of *[tanto](https://dle.rae.es/tanto)* (see meaning 1) as a contraction of "tan mucho":

- Tengo tanto dinero como tú (*I have as much money as you*).

With that out of the way, I would translate the phrase "he is not much of a villain" a little bit more idiomatically using the verb "tener" as

- Él no tiene mucho de villano

which implicitly means "he has not many of the characteristics of a villain". See more examples of "tener mucho de" [on Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=%22tiene%20mucho%20de%22).

So you could say

- Alejandro Magno probablemente no tenía [mucho/tanto] de supervillano de dibujos animados.

Regarding the "Saturday-morning" bit: if you have a reason to want to compare Alexander the Great specifically with a Saturday-morning cartoon suprevillain, then you should say that. Grammar is not there to tell you what to say, but how to say it. So you could say

- Alejandro Magno probablemente no tenía [mucho/tanto] de supervillano de dibujos animados de sábado por la mañana.

You are right that this sounds more "forced" in Spanish than in English, due to the need to use the preposition "de" three times. You could rephrase it a bit and say

- Alejandro Magno probablemente no era el típico supervillano que sale en los dibujos animados del sábado por la mañana.

which has the very similar meaning ("Alexander the Great was probably not the typical supervillain that appears on Saturday-morning cartoons"), but does not repeat the preposition "de" three times.

Comment: Thank you so much! Of your 3 fully phrased translations, the 1st one seems to work best at capturing the particular strain of what I'm intending but also contained in as little of a mouthful as possible. I believe I fully take your point about acquiring the exact meaning of what I want to say, but it feels like the longer renditions of the phrase don't flow smoothly enough to settle into a witty quip... or at least, I'm not at the level where I could say them fast enough for the joke to land, with the effect instead being that my audience is wondering why I'm being so verbose x-D

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to say that his villainy was not cartoonish - exaggerated for dramatic effect rather than being that of a real person - I would suggest

> y Alejandro Magno probablemente no era tan como el malo de la pelicula

The idiomatic expression 'el malo de la pelicula' [the bad guy in the movie] to refer to a character or person with unrealistically exaggerated faults is used often by my wife, who speaks Costa Rican Spanish.

Comment: Here's the full context of the line I describe in my Question: As the speech begins I impersonate Alexander the Great, saying to the audience (dramatically affecting a sinister tone) "You might remember me from my conquest of the world 2600 years ago!" [Insert purple grinning emoji here.] Then I follow that up with an exaggerated evil laugh. Then I apologise for the bad joke, ending the thought with "... and Alexander the Great probably wasn't that much of a cartoon supervillain."

Comment: @Adinkra I think my suggestion seems appropriate, given the context.  However, I don't know how widespread the expression is in the Spanish-speaking world.

Answer (score 1):

What you (playfully) wrote

> ... and Alexander the Great probably wasn't that much of a Saturday-morning cartoon supervillain.

would probably translate more accurately as

> **... y Alejandro Magno probablemente no era *tan* el super villano típico de los dibujos animados de los sábados por la mañana**

The point to stress is that in your English expression you are (even if ironically so) assigning him a bit of a malevolent quality. The word `tan` is often used in Spanish to convey irony (like to say, a bit yeah, but his feared condition is not to be confused with those of the cartoon evil-doers)

Comment: "tan **el** súper villano" is not grammatical Spanish.

Comment: it's a rather common way in the spoken Spanish, at least in Argentina and Uruguay. You can find some written testimonies in books.google  ("`hombre, no te hagas *tan el joven*. Creo que ya pasaste el tiempo de tu primera juventud`")

Comment: Here's the same expresion found into an excertp from a political book "La fuerza es el derecho de las bestias" de Juan Domingo Perón: `Ese imaginado "balance de pagos" del año 1955, es la única cifra negativa de los intercambios citados. Y la inventan porque no había otra cifra negativa. En el correr de los días iremos disciplinando las cifras, reordenándolas y traduciéndolas al lenguaje de la realidad, para que se vea claramente que *no es tan el cuco* como quieren presentarlo. Los ojos se los han puesto donde debía estar la nariz. Es es todo`

Comment: I am from Argentina and have never heard it, let alone read it.

Comment: Interesting that you didn't come across it.  It sounds super natural to me where I grew up (northen Argentina) Though the expression is known enough as to be foundable in print, See "Historias de un oficio perdido. O cómo eran las redacciones antes de internet" `(...)Me gustaba joderlo con su participación en La fiesta de todos, la película de Sergio Renán sobre el mundial 1978, cuando se ponía tan serio, como para decirle "no te hagás tan el recto que estuviste ahí". Lo pasabamos muy bien. Pero Néstor esta grande para Radio Mitre, la radio necesitaba reformularse.`

Comment: Thanks for presenting the examples in context, ipp :) It's really interesting to see how such an idiosyncrasy of grammar can work in different scenarios. ¡Muy apreciado!

Comment: @ipp On rereading the sentences you quoted, the only one that sounds familiar is *hacerse tan el ..." With "ser", it just doesn't sound right to me.